# Windows 10 not allowing Python server.py to connect with client.py

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'm working a tutorial in Python 3.8 that involves sockets and networking. There is a server.py file and a client.py file. I took example code straight out of the Python doc for sockets to see if that would work, and it does not. The server starts and creates a socket and listens for the connection, but I get WinError 10061, the one where the target machine refuses the connection. My OS is Windows 10 and I'm using IDLE. I've looked at my Firewall and set a permission for pythonw.exe to be allowed through, but that has not helped. Anybody have any fixes for me to try? I can't really proceed until I can get the client and server connected.

Comment: you should post at least your code so anyone can help you

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what I’ve been doing wrong. I have been running both server and client files in the same console. I think I have to open two consoles and run one file in each so they can communicate.
(Doh!)
I’m at work so I can’t test it right now. Just in case anyone else has been befuddled by this .

Yes, I did not realize that each file had to run in its own instance of IDLE, but that makes perfect sense now. A socket won’t connect to itself!